# Difference between byte size of C-String

Tags: c, char, byte, sizeof

I been working in a project for my Data Networks class and they ask me to concatenate a header like this:

```
struct ip
{
    unsigned long a;
    unsigned long b;
    unsigned int l;
} IP;
```

And a message which it's a char* let's say "Hello".

So, I use this method to concatenate those two in a single char*:

```
memcpy(sendBuf, (void*)&sendHeader, sizeof(sendHeader));
memcpy(&sendBuf[sizeof(sendHeader)], readMessage, lengthMessage);
```

With lengthMessage being the number of characters of the message +1 which is the null termination character.

So, sendBuf it's defined like this:

```
char sendBuf[BUFLEN + 1]   // BUF_LEN = 128
```

And then I put this char* in a queue defined like this:

```
concurrency::concurrent_queue<char*> IP_in_queue;
```

So, I want to check if the information it's correct, so I just check everything:

```
char* s;
IP_in_queue.try_pop(s);
numbytes = sizeof(s);
// Copy from buf to the header
memcpy( (void*)&readHeader, s, sizeof( IP_PACKET_HEADER_T));
// Copy message part
memcpy( sendedString, &s[sizeof(IP_PACKET_HEADER_T)], numbytes - sizeof(IP_PACKET_HEADER_T));
// Append \0 to the end
sendedString[numbytes - sizeof(IP_PACKET_HEADER_T)] = '\0';
```

So, before I queue my char*, we know that the size of sendBuf is 129, but when I check the number of bytes after I dequeue it's way too different, the value of number of bytes it's 4, but even in that way I get the information right, so I don't understand that, maybe I missing some important things, but the variable numbytes shouldn't be at least more?

I hope I made myself clear and maybe someone can explain me this a little bit better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sizeof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) does not tell you the length of the string - it tells you the size of the type `char*`, which on a 32-bit machine is 4 bytes.  You want [`strlen`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strlen/), the number of bytes in the string.

But even that isn't what you want.  Your structure `IP` can have nulls in it, so even `strlen` won't give you a correct answer.  If you put your string first instead of last you can fix that, but I'd consider that kind of a hack.  You should add the size explicitly to the start of your message.

Comment: So, If I understand you right, I should store a length variable of the concatenation process, let's say my message is Hello, so it would be 5 bytes plus the sizeof of my IP structure, right? And in every concatenation process store the real length of my char* ?

Comment: Doesn't matter whether you store `5` or `5+sizeof(IP)`, as long as you can reconstruct the size of all of the pieces from just `s`.  Make sure you store the real length in a way that you can extract it unambiguously from `s` as well.

Comment: But that's my question, the real size in bytes of that packet it would be 5 + sizeof(IP) right?, Yes, I know how to store the concatenate header + message with his size, but the question it's how to get the real size of the concatenation.

Comment: If you can't figure that out, you're in trouble.  Count the bytes you're `memcpy`ing.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, I was really confuse haha sorry! It was a really stupid mistake. Thanks for all the help!